# PostgreSQL Change ALL items(TABLE, SEQ, FUNC, VIEW) GRANT/OWNER in one query

Tags: postgresql

**GRANT permissions or set OWNER to all pgsql items in one query without creating function.**

- views
- functions
- tables
- sequences

Because I've spend a lot of time trying to find such solution. I just found few separate queries or functions but no sql that would do whole job at once.

Maybe this will be helpful for someone.

1. Fill `WHERE s IN(?)` with schemes you need.
2. Create query you want to execute on all objects in `LOOP` block similar to this:

   `EXECUTE 'ALTER ' || tbl.o || ' ' || tbl.sn || ' OWNER TO admin';` or

   `EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || tbl.o || ' ' || tbl.sn || ' TO admin';`

**SQL query:**

```
DO $$DECLARE tbl record;
BEGIN
    FOR tbl IN 
        SELECT o, s || '.' || n sn
        FROM (
            SELECT 'FUNCTION' o, nspname s, proname || '(' || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' n
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n 
            JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON pronamespace = n.oid

            UNION

            SELECT 'TABLE' o, nspname s, relname n
            FROM pg_class c
            JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
            WHERE   nspname NOT LIKE E'pg\\_%' AND 
                nspname <> 'information_schema' AND 
                relkind IN ('r','S','v')
            ) tbl
        WHERE s IN('public')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER ' || tbl.o || ' ' || tbl.sn || ' OWNER TO admin';
        -- EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || tbl.o || ' ' || tbl.sn || ' TO admin';
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `reassign owned`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html

Comment: You have to know all roles that are used. In my case I had to execute it on few databases where almost all tables had different role. This also doesn't allow to do other queries like grants. Still +1 for nice solution I didn't know. This one will be helpful in future for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use pl/pgsql because `ALTER TABLE` statements are unplanned.

There is one key thing you should do for your code though and that is that you need to escape args in your `ALTER TABLE` statement. Conceptually you want to change:

```
    EXECUTE 'ALTER ' || tbl.o || ' ' || tbl.sn || ' OWNER TO admin';
```

to

```
    EXECUTE 'ALTER ' || tbl.o || ' ' || quote_ident(tbl.sn) || ' OWNER TO admin';
```

But that will on the tables, so really you need to add the quote_ident into your top-level function.  So instead of that change, change:

```
SELECT 'FUNCTION' o, nspname s, proname || '(' || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' n
```

to

```
 SELECT 'FUNCTION' o, nspname s, quote_ident(proname) || '(' || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' n
```

and

```
 SELECT 'TABLE' o, nspname s, relname n
```

to

```
 SELECT 'TABLE' o, nspname s, quote_ident(relname) n
```

Otherwise you are in for a fun surprise if anyone does this:

```
 CREATE TABLE "pg_autid owner to postgres; drop schema public cascade; --"(foo int);
```